# query registry on windows 2000

Tags: windows, registry

I need to query some registry values on windows 2000. I was able to do it on windows XP by using "reg query" command, but for some reason, I can not find the same command on windows 2000. Does anybody know the equivalent command or something?  I kind of have read an article that it needs to be installed from an additional windows 2000 CD-ROM. Does anybody know about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Windows Support Tools from `\support\tools` on your Windows 2000 installation CD.  This contains reg.exe.

Or, download and install the [Windows NT4 resource kit support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19109).  This version of reg.exe was released for Windows NT4 but will probably run in Windows 2000.  (The Windows 2000 version does not appear to be available online.)